# Can't use SKShapeNode in inout function

Tags: ios, swift, return, skshapenode, inout

So, like my `SKSpriteNode`s, I am trying to create a function to make me a default physics body.

Here's my `DefaultBody.swift` I created:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

enum Type {
    case rectangle
    case circle
}

// Create new default physics body
func createPhysicsBodySprite(for body: inout SKSpriteNode, type: Type) {

    // Create new physics body
    switch type {
    case .rectangle:
        body.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: body.frame)
    case .circle:
        body.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: body.frame.width / 2)
    }
    body.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    body.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    body.physicsBody?.pinned = false
    body.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    body.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    body.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    body.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    body.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

}

func createPhysicsBodyShape(for body: inout SKShapeNode, type: Type) {

    // Create new physics body
    switch type {
    case .rectangle:
        body.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: body.frame)
    case .circle:
        body.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: body.frame.width / 2)
    }
    body.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    body.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    body.physicsBody?.pinned = false
    body.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    body.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    body.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
    body.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    body.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

}
```

Here I can call the Sprite version easily:

[image]

However, although I can do that with an `SKSpriteNode`, my `SKShapeNode` function does not work, as I get this error:

[image]

This does not work, so if I get rid of the `inout` in the function and add it as a return, it now works (using the call commented out in the above image)

Is there any reason to this, and how can I use `inout` instead of returning the `SKShapeNode`?

***Note:*** a `PhysicsBody` can be set to an `SKShapeNode`

Both are `var` and not `let` as shown here, and so *should* be mutable:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to pass an inout parameter, you must add `&`:

```
createPhyscisBodyShape(for: &topBar, type: .rectangle)
```

You did this with the `&ball`. I wonder why you forgot the `&` the second time.

Anyway, you don't need `inout` in the first place. `SKSpriteNode` and `SKShapeNode` are classes. That means as long as you don't set `body` to something else with an assignment statement, the changes you made to `body` will be reflected in the parameter you passed.

Remove the inout and it should work fine.

Comment: My code did actually have the ampersand (`&`), but for some reason I didn't copy and paste that correctly, oops. I will try not using `inout` now

Comment: @George_E_2 are you sure it's a copy and paste mistake? I didn't see a & in the image.

Comment: I'm quite surprised it works! I now understand how I don't need the inout. Thank you!

Comment: It is when I was testing when it didn't work, I had copied and pasted the commented version and got rid of the variable assignment which left no &

Answer (score 0):

pass value to function of `inout` params , we should use `&`

**createPhyscisBodyShape(for: &topBar ,  type: .rectangle)**

check with this link https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID545